# Can't seem to print variable within <string> </string>

Tags: string, bash, printf, echo

Ran into another roadblock. I'm to generate text that looks like the following.

```
<dict>
            <key>cfurl_string</key>
            <string>/Applications/Launchpad.app</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>cfurl_string</key>
            <string>/Applications/Safari.app</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>cfurl_string</key>
            <string>/Applications/Photos.app</string>
        </dict>
```

It's not too complex, but here is the code used to generate this:

```
for i in $(cut -d "," -f1 $1); do
 printf '<dict>\n'
 printf ' <key>cfurl_string</key>\n'
 printf ' <string>'
 echo -n "$i"
 printf '</string>\n'
 printf '</dict>\n'

done
echo "</array>"
```

where $1 is a csv file that a user specifies. A column contains a list of application locations:

```
/Applications/Launchpad
/Applications/Safari
/Applications/Pages
/Applications/Numbers
/Applications/Keynote
/Applications/Photos
/Applications/iMovie
/Applications/GarageBand
/Applications/Microsoft Word
/Applications/Microsoft Excel
```

When I run the script without the variable, I get this:

```
<array>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string></string>
</dict>
</array>
```

But if I run the command with the variable printed, it causes it to act weird EXCEPT for the last value in the loop.

```
.app</string>lications/GarageBand
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
.app</string>lications/Microsoft Word
</dict>
<dict>
 <key>cfurl_string</key>
 <string>/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

I've tried tricking it, but once I get it in the way that i want it, it acts weird. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when I do that, I get this:

`✗ cat -v dockcsv.csv
/Applications/Launchpad^M
/Applications/Safari^M
/Applications/Pages^M
/Applications/Numbers^M
/Applications/Keynote^M
/Applications/Photos^M
/Applications/iMovie^M
/Applications/GarageBand^M
/Applications/Microsoft Word^M
/Applications/Microsoft Excel%`

Comment: Clearly you've got CRLFs -- DOS-style newlines -- about.

Comment: BTW, see the *very first item* in the "Before Asking About Problematic Code" section of the [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: rookie mistake, this would have helped so much. noted and appreciated

Comment: Read these: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your csv file for non-printable characters: `cat -A file.csv` or `cat -v file.csv`

If you find something like `^M`, then I recommend: `dos2unix file.csv`

Comment: yeah I'm getting the ^M, installing dos2unix now and will report back.

Comment: If you don't have dos2unix, plenty of other ways to fix this. Opening the file in vim and running `:set fileformat=unix` before saving it will do the trick.

Comment: wow that actually fixed it for me... I never would have guessed that to be the case. Is this common?

Comment: Yes, if the file was created on a Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Replace loop for by while :

```
while IFS="," read i
do
 printf '<dict>\n'
 printf ' <key>cfurl_string</key>\n'
 printf ' <string>'
 printf ' <string>%s</string>\n' "$i"
 printf '</string>\n'
 printf '</dict>\n'
done < "$1"
printf "</array>\n"
```

Comment: `echo -n` is needlessly nonportable -- shells aren't required to do anything with `-n` other than print it as a string on stdout. Safer to use `printf '%s' "$i"` to print `$i` with no newline. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: That said, since you're already using `printf`, you could use `printf '  <string>%s</string>\n' "$i"`. Not that that'll help with the OP's problem (caused by stray carriage returns).

Comment: I agree with you, I have write to fast